# "atmosphere of" vs "atmosphere from"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, prepositions

Regarding the sentence *The hectic atmosphere caused by household chores and meal preparation fills the house*

Can I substitute *caused by* with *of* or *from* and still maintain the same meaning? My concern is that it would make it less clear and kind of unnatural

If you have any other sugestions I'd highly appreciate it

Comment: They're close, but strictly speaking, they change the meaning somewhat. An atmosphere *caused by* something is arguably distinct from the atmosphere *of* that something, just as frustration *caused by* someone isn't quite the same as that someone's own frustration. The atmosphere *from* chores etc sounds more physical than metaphoric. Of the three, *of* sounds most natural to me, unless you want to distinguish the *hectic atmosphere* from whatever atmosphere the chores and meal preparation have - in which case, retain the original (*caused by*).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Lawrence. I'm going to be using of.